# Having trouble reading in created struct types from a text file

Tags: c++, struct, ifstream

I am trying to read in information from a .txt file and putting the information in a previously created struct type.

Here is the struct definition:

```
struct String
{
   const char* text;
   int sz;  //length of string not including null terminator
};
```

and here is the code giving me the error(it is just a massive error and at the end it says "cannot convert 'title' to type 'signed char*'

```
CDs* createCDs(const char* file_name)
{
   ifstream input_file;
   input_file.open(file_name);

   String* artist;
   input_file >> artist;

   String* title;
   input_file >> title;
```

Also the info being read in is just text. Any help or input would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Uhh, why so many unnecessary pointers...

Comment: @awesomeyi This is an assignment for my intro to C++ class and the purpose is to get us comfortable with using an uncomfortable amount of pointers haha

Comment: `const char* text;` wouldn't be very useful for such `String` struct :-/ ...

Comment: Reading data into a *pointer to `String` object* doesn't seem very promising to me. I'd try reading into `String` object instead...

Comment: @CiaPan i tried doing input_file >> artist->text; instead and it still didn't work :/

Comment: Did you make `artist` to point to some `String` object? If you read into `artist->text` when `artist` is uninitilized, then you can't succeed.

Answer (score 3):

The two variables `artist` and `title` are *pointers*, not objects. Thus, you're not seeing the same behavior if you did something like the following:

```
String artist;
input_file >> artist;
```

Assuming of course that you had an appropriate overload of `operator>>()` (I will explain that in a bit).

When you tried to read into a pointer, you got an error because the compiler couldn't find an overload of the stream extraction operator (`operator>>()`) that took as a right hand argument a pointer to a `String`. The reason you saw `"cannot convert 'title' to type 'signed char*'` at the bottom was because the compiler was listing all the candidate overloads and the respective errors they emit when trying to convert `artist` or `title` to their right hand argument.

---

If you need to use a pointer, than it has to be initialized to a valid object. And you must dereference the pointer to get a reference to the object it points to, so that the stream can read the data into it:

```
String* artist = new String;
input_file >> *artist;
```

But then again, you don't actually *need* pointers here. This can be done by keeping the objects on the stack:

```
String artist;
input_file >> artist;
```

If for some reason you still need to use pointers, then you must remember to deallocate the memory the pointer points to (if assigned to data created with `new`). You do this using `delete`:

```
// when you are finished using the data artist or title points to
delete artist;
delete title;
```

Alternatively, you can use a [`std::unique_ptr<String>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). A `std::unique_ptr<>` is a container that will manage the memory for you when it goes out of scope, so it is unnecessary for you to deallocate the resource yourself:

```
{
    std::unique_ptr<String> title;
    // ...
} // <= the resource held by title is released
```

If your compiler doesn't support `std::unique_ptr<>` which is a new (C++11) object, you can use [`std::shared_ptr<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

---

When incorporating stream I/O semantics into a user-defined class, it is conventional that you provide an overload of the stream operators, which subsequently extracts data into the class' data members. It allows the syntax:

```
X x;
istream_object >> x;
ostream_object << x;
```

Judging from what you've shown us, I do not believe that you have provided an overload for *input* stream objects. Here's what one would look like for your `String` class:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, String& s)
{
    // code for extraction goes here
}
```

If you have private members which the extractor needs access to, you can declare it as a friend of the class.